# How to implement OCaml function with the next type?

Tags: types, functional-programming, ocaml, type-inference, curry-howard

I am studying Curry–Howard correspondence.

Given propositional logic statement: `¬(p ∨ q) -> (¬p ∧ ¬q)`.

I need to define a type (as proposition) and a function (as a proof) in OCaml.

I have defined type but do not know how to implement function:

```
type empty = | 
type ('a , 'b) coprod = Left of 'a | Right of 'b
let ex513: (('p, 'q) coprod -> empty) -> ('p -> empty) * ('q -> empty) = fun ?
```

What I did before posting a question:

1. [I have verified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120187/do-de-morgans-laws-hold-in-propositional-intuitionistic-logic) that this statement is provable in intuitionistic logic.
2. Tried to understand constructively: if there is `function1` that converts proof of p or proof of q to ⊥ then we can construct tuple (`function2` that converts proof of p to ⊥, `function3` that converts proof of q to ⊥). Implementation `(function1(p), function1(q))`
3. Implemented similar task to better understand the problem: `p ∨ q -> ¬(¬p ∧ ¬q)`.

code:

```
let func1: ('p, 'q) coprod -> ('p-> empty) * ('q-> empty) -> empty = fun x (f, g)->
    match x with 
    | Left x -> f(x)
    | Right x -> g(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining

```ml
type 'a not = 'a -> empty
```

for the sake of concision,
it is indeed a good idea to write a function

```
let left_branch: type p q. (p,q) coprod not -> p not = ...
```

and

```ml
let right_branch: type p q. (p,q) coprod not -> q not = ...
```

Once you have defined both functions (in other words proved the corresponding lemma), the solution can be reached by applying both lemma:

```ml
let de_morgan_law: type p q. (p,q) coprod not -> p not * q not =
  fun not_p_or_q -> left_branch not_p_or_q, right_branch not_p_or_q
```

If you have trouble writing the `left_branch` (or right function), remember that

```ml
let left x = Left x
```

has type `'a -> ('a,'any) coprod`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I could not imagine calling 2 functions in 'parallel' and then combining result. All the time I was thinking in sequences: f1(x1) (f2(x2)).
Here is my implementation. I will do your code suggestions later.
`let left_branch: (('p, 'q) coprod  -> empty) -> 'p -> empty = fun f x -> f(Left(x));; 
  let right_branch: (('p, 'q) coprod  -> empty) -> 'q -> empty = fun f x -> f(Right(x));;
  let ex513: (('p, 'q) coprod -> empty) -> ('p -> empty) * ('q -> empty) = fun f -> left_branch(f),right_branch(f) `